# Tokbox video publish unfocused (Android)

Tags: android, camera, tokbox

I am using tokbox for video chat and I want to take pictures of printed documents. When I am trying this on a Samsung s7edge my captured image is so unfocused I cannot read it. When I am trying this on a Nexus 6p the image is fine.

It is not a resolution problem, I am always using CameraCaptureResolution.HIGH

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it:

I used this class:
https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/blob/master/Custom-Video-Driver/app/src/main/java/com/tokbox/android/tutorials/customvideodriver/CustomVideoCapturer.java

Changed the init function:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    mCamera = Camera.open(mCameraIndex);
    mCurrentDeviceInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraIndex, mCurrentDeviceInfo);
    try{
        //set camera to continually auto-focus
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the swapCamera as well, so every time the back camera comes into play It must have autofocus.

And in my Activity, onConnected:

```
CustomVideoCapturer  mCapturer = new CustomVideoCapturer(a) ;
mPublisher = new Publisher.Builder(this)
    .capturer(mCapturer)
    .resolution(Publisher.CameraCaptureResolution.HIGH).build();
```